# Is there anything out there to help handle "field level" authorization for ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know you can use the Authorize attribute to control access to a Controller or ActionMethod... but what about more fine grained control?  It seems common to have specific fields be allowed/disallowed based on a user's role, for instance.  Maybe on an employee profile the employee can edit his profile information, but only a supervisor can change his job title...

Optimally I'd like to be able to develop views, models and controllers normally and have a configuration page on the website that site admins could then use to configure authorization at whatever granularity is required.  In other words the programmers shouldn't worry about it (except for the guy writing/integrating that specific part of the system.)

I can envision DisplayFor and EditorFor checking attributes to render fields as ReadOnly, Hidden, etc... and maybe the attributes get added at run time from an Authorization Provider of some kind.

The question is:  Is there a framework or something out there that already does this?

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom ModelMetaDataProvider that will allow you to alter the metadata for each model and it's properties before they make it to the view. The built in helpers will not render a field if it's metadata value ShowForEdit = false or ShowForDisplay = false.

You can utilize a rules engine or some other ACL to manipulate the metadata on each model and property to get most of the behavior your looking for out of the box without touching the built in helpers. On edge cases where you need more control you can write your own helpers and pass more complex data in the metadata.AdditionalValues dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement security at field level using HtmlHelper. In the following example they used textbox only implementation but it can easily be extended for all type of controls:

http://bartreyserhove.blogspot.ca/2008/12/field-level-security-using-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question... I know I COULD write helpers, custome displayfors and editorfors and all that... but A) I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution and B) I'm hoping someone else has already done it!

Comment: I do not think anybody has done it but I am looking to write a plugin for it, if you can wait for 2 weeks then you can use it :) If somebody has already done it then it will be great if you can let me know too.